# When should we expect an answer

Tags: word-usage

What is the proper way to ask this question? 
When should we expect an answer or When can we expect an answer

Answer (score 4):

Basically, this depends on the context. To put it very simply:

If you are demanding an answer/reply from someone where you are in a position of (higher) authority, you can ask:

> When should we expect an answer?

On the other hand, when the tables are turned, and you are not the one demanding (for instance when you are trying to sell something to a client), then you may ask-

> When can we expect an answer?

Comment: +1 Would it sound weird to say "When *may* we expect an answer?"  (I'm second-guessing the can/may issue here)

Comment: I would say it's certainly acceptable, although it _does_ seem like a very refined way of **when can we**, too formal for day-to-day conversations. Google's first hit of **when may we** points to this [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1861/03/13/news/police-commissioners-superintendent-kennedy-vs-detective-williamson.html) article dated 1861 :)

Comment: The only drawback of the very polite "When may we expect an answer?" formulation is that it invites the dismissive response "Whenever you like."

Comment: Of course, the snarky "You can *expect* it whenever you like" retort can be used against most of the ways of phrasing the request.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context. ***Should*** implies obligation, for example when companies say they will deal with complaints within a set number of days. ***Can*** has more the meaning *When will you be able to provide an answer?*

Answer (score 0):

For internal company communications (where directness is important but so is avoiding hurt feelings), one common approach is to ask for an "eta" (short for "estimated time of arrival"). This situation arises frequently in publishing, where designers need copy from editors, editors need manuscripts from authors, and production people need finished copy from everyone else.

At one publishing house where I worked, a standard email header was "ETA for Xxxxx story?" and the body of the message was approximately "Please let me know when you think you'll have the Xxxxx ready for me to work on. Thanks!"

I can't tell whether you are directing your communication/request for information to someone out-of-house or whether it will remain in-house, but you could frame it this way:

> Please send us an eta for the answer we've requested, so we can plan accordingly.

I don't know how successful this approach would be in other environments and cultures—but in a California business setting, I think it comes across as direct and reasonable without being pushy.